# validar caracter en formulario

Tags: php, html

hola quiero que en mi formulario valide que el carácter vaya obligativamente "-" y que arroje un mensajito de error que si es que fue escrito en imput

```
          <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="rut" class="form-control" placeholder="rut" minlength="9" maxlength="10"required autofocus>
      </div>
```

Comment: Orientación: Usa el atributo pattern (solo funciona cuando haces un submit del formulario): https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Comment: pattern="[0-9]+-[a-z0-9]" nose si esta bien pero el formato debería ser 11223344-5

Comment: En ese enlace que te he pasado en mi anterior comentario dale al botón "Try it yourself" y puedes hacer las pruebas que necesites editando el código alli mismo.

Comment: al final encontre una pagina llamada regexr[enlance](https://regexr.com/) y busque pattern de la comunidad

Comment: Si te funciona, perfecto. Veo que hay muchísimos donde escoger o modificar a tu gusto.

Comment: una consulta me deja usar igual el submit ?

Comment: No se lo que quieres decir... si usas una pattern y no se cumple entonces el submit se para, no se ejecuta, hasta que el usuario lo sepa poner bien

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="off">
        <input name="rut" pattern="^[.0-9]{6,11}\-?[kK0-9]{1}$" title="el formato correcto 11222333-4" required>
        <input type="submit" id="enviar" value="envia">
    </form>
</body>
</html>` probando este para luego enviarlo al código y al oficial pero igual funciona el submit aun asi escribiendo mal el patter

Comment: Prueba a ponerle un `type="text"` al input.  Fíjate lo que dicen en ese enlace: `Note: The pattern attribute works with the following input types: text, date, search, url, tel, email, and password.`.   Tu input no tiene ningún type.